# Azure build pipeline doesn't work: unable to create directory D:\a\1\a\

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I'm learning Azure DevOps and I'm stuck with a build pipeline.
The project is a simple .NET Core web app and this is the YAML file

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/azpipe.csproj'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\'
    platform: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

When I run the pipeline I get error and this is the log

```
Publish:
  azpipe -> D:\a\1\s\obj\Debug\net5.0\PubTmp\Out\
_TransformWebConfig:
  No web.config found. Creating 'D:\a\1\s\obj\Debug\net5.0\PubTmp\Out\web.config'
_PrepareForMsDeployPublish:
  Creating directory "D:\a\1\a\ \p:platform=Release \p:configuration=Release \p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 \p:_MSDeployUserAgent=VSTS_ac5aa204-3429-4edf-ae3d-777f0b31c141_build_9_0\".
##[warning]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeployPackage.targets(156,5): Warning MSB3191: Unable to create directory "D:\a\1\a\ \p:platform=Release \p:configuration=Release \p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 \p:_MSDeployUserAgent=VSTS_ac5aa204-3429-4edf-ae3d-777f0b31c141_build_9_0\". The given path's format is not supported.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeployPackage.targets(156,5): warning MSB3191: Unable to create directory "D:\a\1\a\ \p:platform=Release \p:configuration=Release \p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 \p:_MSDeployUserAgent=VSTS_ac5aa204-3429-4edf-ae3d-777f0b31c141_build_9_0\". The given path's format is not supported. [D:\a\1\s\azpipe.csproj]
  The previous error was converted to a warning because the task was called with ContinueOnError=true.
  Build continuing because "ContinueOnError" on the task "MakeDir" is set to "true".
```

and so far whit many of this rows.

I tried several solution found but I cannot get it to work.
Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the warning message "`Warning MSB3191: Unable to create directory "D:\a\1\a\ \p:platform=Release \p:configuration=Release \p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 \p:_MSDeployUserAgent=VSTS_ac5aa204-3429-4edf-ae3d-777f0b31c141_build_9_0\". The given path's format is not supported.`"

It appears that the given path's format is not correct. And in your yaml file, you specified the project but not the solution.

Please specify the solution instead of the project, reference below format:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My mistake, I didn't notice the format of the path. Thanks!